# What's the best db structure to represent the relationships within a family if the base-object is a Person

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

I have a large DB full or people called PERSONS.

I want to store their relationship to one another in a separate table.

I am thinking something like this:

```
FAMILY
PERSON_IDS: 123, 345, 678
RELATIONS:  self, brother, daughter
```

Using a 'self' flag to indicate the person referring the relation-ship from. So, in the  example 123 would be a man, 345 is his brother and 678 is a woman, his daughter. I.e, the gender information could be derived from the relationship.

Is this the right way to go about it?

Or would it be more efficient to have only 2 PERSONS per row and one relationship-type

```
PERSON_IDS: 123, 456
RELATION: brother
```

-

```
PERSON_IDS: 123, 678
RELATION: daughter
```

Or is it better to have a male/female field per person and the relation-ship table only specify eg "sibling".

Or should I have a table with PARENTS only and store the gender with the PERSON?

```
TABLE PARENTS:
PARENT_ID: 123
CHILD_ID: 678
```

The aim is to display related people when a Person is displayed. The design should be optimized for performance & speed rather than ease of administration.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: All of the above; and none. Describe, in detail, the relationships you need to capture first. Are you capturing step-relationships as well as natural ones. Etc.?

Comment: Treat natural and step relationships the same.

Comment: One of the common problems of modeling families is that peoplewant to model them as hierarchies. They're not. They're networks, and they have loops. "Parent" and "child" have biological meaning that sometimes conflicts with legal meaning. "Husband/wife" relationships can simultaneously be "Husband/niece" or "Husband/daughter" relationships.

Comment: Also, any time you're tempted to follow an ID number with a comma, you're going the wrong way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a many-to-many relationship: each person can have many relatives and also be a relative of many people. Assuming your Person table has a primary key named `Id`, you could have a table, which holds the relationship between two people as well as the kind of relationship they have. It would be useful to also have a table with all the possible kinds of relationships, something like this:

```
Relationship(Id, Kind)
Family(Person_Id, Relative_Id, Relationship_Id)
```

So if you have the following data for Person and Relationship tables:

```
Person:             Relationship:
Id | Name           Id | Kind
 1 | John            1 | Father
 2 | Mike            2 | Sister
 3 | Susan
```

and the following for Family table:

```
P_Id | Rel_Id | Relation_Id
 1   |   2    |      1
 1   |   3    |      1
 2   |   3    |      2
```

Family table is saying that John is the father of Mike and Susan, and that Mike's sister is Susan. I think this could be a good approach, but of course, as almost everything in databases design, this solution is arguable.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a good solution. Initially, I was hoping that this is a 'problem' that is quite common and that some sort of standardized way of doing this had established itself already. Oh well...  live and learn...

Comment: You may also wish to add a `reverse_relation_id` column to show the relation of `Relative_Id` to `Person_Id`.  I.e., Son, Daughter, Brother.